# Java FX preventing UI from freezing

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I want the user to wait until my method call to download a file, which might take around 2 to 3 minutes, completes. I created a new thread for the method call and calling it inside `run()` method. Based on the return value, a message should be displayed, whether successful or error. Hence I had to use `join()`. But this still freezes since the UI is still waiting for the method call to complete. How can I overcome this issue? (Basically, I need to use a thread for UI to not to freeze, and at the same time, I want to display a message based on the method's return value)

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
   @Override
   public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
      processMsg.setText("Do not close. This may take few minutes...");
      Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
         @Override
         public void run() {
            try {
                   ret = /*Method-call-which-takes-long-time*/
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                     Logger.getLogger(JavaFXApplication1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                     Logger.getLogger(JavaFXApplication1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
         }
      });
      t1.start();
      try {
           t1.join();
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(JavaFXApplication1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
      if (ret != null){
         if (ret.equals("TRUE")){
            pane.getChildren().remove(processMsg);
            processMsg.setText("File downloaded at location: "+ chosenDir.getAbsolutePath());
            pane.add(processMsg,0,11,2,1);
         }
         else{
            pane.getChildren().remove(processMsg);
            processMsg.setText(ret);
            pane.add(processMsg,0,11,2,1);
         }
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. and don't forget to read up on concurrency in (and how it is supported by) fx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Based on the return value, a message should be displayed, whether successful or error. Hence I had to use `join()`.

This assumption is wrong. There are ways to update the GUI from a background thread. [`Platform.runLater`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater(java.lang.Runnable)) is the most flexible one, but in this case I simply recommend using [`Task`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html), which allows you to add handlers via  `onSucceeded` and `onFailed` properties that are invoked when the `call` logic completes with or without throwing an exception:

```
Task<MyReturnType> task = new Task<MyReturnType>() {

    @Override
    protected MyReturnType call() throws Exception {
        return someLongCalculation(); // may throw an exception
    }

};

task.setOnSucceeded(evt -> {
    // we're on the JavaFX application thread here
    MyReturnType result = task.getValue();
    label.setText(result.toString());

});

task.setOnFailed(evt -> {
    // we're on the JavaFX application thread here
    label.setText("Error: " + task.getException().getMessage());
});
new Thread(task).start(); // alternatively use ExecutorService
```

`Task.updateValue`, `Task.updateMessage` and `Task.updateProgress` allow you to communicate partial results back that can be observed using the `value`, `message` and `progress` properties; those properties are updated on the JavaFX application thread.

Answer (score 2):

I advise you to check this [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm) on how to handle business logic outside of UI component.

Also, regarding your question using CompletableFuture would be of a great help to do such asynchronous work.

To be specific, `whenComplete()` would help if you use the download process in a `CompletableFuture` then display the message afterwards.

Here is a reference for [whenComplete()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#whenComplete-java.util.function.BiConsumer-)

Comment: Yes, I agree with this answer. A more standard way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You may be aware JavaFX rendering is handled by the thread named JavaFX Application Thread. You can see the threads in Eclipse Debug mode. So, if this thread is made to wait for another, then rendering will freeze. That is what is happening here.

### What you may do

1. When this button is clicked, disable the buttons that you don't want the user to click.
2. Use a container to poll for the results. This can be a global queue or elegantly implemented using RxJava `BehaviorSubject` or some other suitable implementation of `Subject`.
3. When the time consuming method has completed, it will populate the queue with the result or call `onNext()` on the RxJava `Subject`.
4. When the listener of the queue or the `Subject` gets the value, it reenables the buttons.

Let me see if I can quickly put together a sample. In the meantime, you can try on your own.